# Azure CLI - Copy files from one container prefix to another

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-cli

I have storage account "mysa" and container "mycontainer". Inside This container there are two prefixes ("4.1.2.3" and "latest") with files under them. I am trying to copy files from "4.1.2.3" prefix to "latest":

```
az storage blob copy start-batch --source-container "mycontainer" --pattern "4.1.2.3/*" --destination-container "mycontainer/latest" --account-name mysa
```

Actual structure becomes
__ mycontainer
______ 4.1.2.3
______ latest
_________ 4.1.2.3

How to correctly move files from one prefix to another using Azure CLI?

Comment: Are you trying to copy blobs from `4.1.2.3` folder to `latest` folder? For example, if there's a file called `1.png` under `4.1.2.3`, you want that file to copy to `latest` folder so that the path would become `latest\1.png`?

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri exactly!

Comment: Do you like to use AzCopy? It's easy to do this.

Comment: @NancyXiong no, i am trying to configure azure devops pipeline, there is no azcopy jobs, but there is azure cli.

Comment: @VadzimDvorak Did you manages to get around this issue? I have tried moving the subpath into the source-container, so in your case --source-container "mycontainer/4.1.2.3", but that seems to break the ability to use wildcards in the pattern (it works if you define the file, but * doesnt work)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to copy files from one container prefix to another
Instead of that you can use the below `PowerShell` script to achieve this.

Thanks  [mohit varma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6049604/mohit-verma) Your script help me lot to find the solution.

```
$SourceStorageAccount = "source storageaccount"
$SourceStorageKey = "source key"
$DestStorageAccount = "dest storageaccount"
$DestStorageKey = "dest key"

#here added source and destination separately you can use the script for same & differenct container prefix also 
 
$SourceStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $SourceStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $SourceStorageKey
$DestStorageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $DestStorageAccount -StorageAccountKey $DestStorageKey

$Containers = Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $SourceStorageContext
$sourceprefixname ="4.1.2.3"
$destPrefixname = "latest"

foreach($Container in $Containers)
{
    $ContainerName = $Container.Name
    if (!((Get-AzureStorageContainer -Context $DestStorageContext) | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $ContainerName }))
    {   
        Write-Output "Creating new container $ContainerName"
        New-AzureStorageContainer -Name $ContainerName -Permission Off -Context $DestStorageContext -ErrorAction Stop
    }

    $Blobs = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -Container $ContainerName
    $BlobCpyAry = @() #Create array of objects
    $folders = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

    #Do the copy of everything
    

    foreach ($Blob in $Blobs)
    {
    if($Blob.Name.StartsWith($sourceprefixname))
    {
        $BlobName = $Blob.Name
        $DestBlobNamestr = $BlobName.Replace($sourceprefixname,$destPrefixname)
       Write-Output "Copying $BlobName from $ContainerName"
       $BlobCopy = Start-CopyAzureStorageBlob -Context $SourceStorageContext -SrcContainer $ContainerName -SrcBlob $BlobName -DestContext $DestStorageContext -DestContainer $ContainerName -DestBlob $DestBlobNamestr
       $BlobCpyAry += $BlobCopy
    }
       
    }
    #Check Status
    foreach ($BlobCopy in $BlobCpyAry)
    {
       #Could ignore all rest and just run $BlobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState but I prefer output with % copied
       $CopyState = $BlobCopy | Get-AzureStorageBlobCopyState
       $Message = $CopyState.Source.AbsolutePath + " " + $CopyState.Status + " {0:N2}%" -f (($CopyState.BytesCopied/$CopyState.TotalBytes)*100) 
       Write-Output $Message
    }
}
```